# Can I change the brightness threshold of the slider?

Tags: display, brightness

I have an Intel Graphics card. The brightness range goes from 0 (black) to 976 (full brightness). I would like to set the minimum brightness to 6 since it is the minimum brightness in which I can see the screen. How can I do that?

```
 $ dir /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight
 actual_brightness  bl_power  brightness  device  max_brightness  power subsystem  type  uevent
```

I can manually set the brightness with: `echo X> /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` (where X is a number between 0-976)

It would be also okay if I could increase the sensitivity of the slider between the values 5-50, so that it goes 5 by 5 or something. Right now it goes 50 by 50 and it's too much change in low light conditions.